# Problem with Identity scaffolding in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I made a MVC project, that includes 2 projects.

1. class library (.NET Core) - i have my models and services/options here
2. ASP.NET Core Web Application - Controllers, views here

I want to add identity to my project. So i found the following NuGet Packages

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores

I used `public class NameDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` in my DbContext class.

I clicked Add on the Web-project -> choose "New Scaffolded Item" -> pictures below

[What i want to choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxOM9.png)

[The Error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka7x3.png)

Any ideas?

EDIT:

i can see in my database that the tables are created, after the NuGet Packages and the `add-migration` & `update-database` commands that followed.

I also tried my DbContext class without the `<IdentityUser>` like this

`public class NameDbContext : IdentityDbContext`

Comment: You can try to updated all NuGet packages from Tools->Nuget Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Updates tab -> Update All.

Comment: This seems to work, thank you.
I have encountered another problem with setting it up (display on the app when i debug), but i'll try to work it out on my own for now.
I used older versions because i am following a project. The devil is in the details.

Comment: Hi @Syrrah,If my answer is helpful,can you [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?Thanks! And if there is any other question,Welcome back to ask questions again.

Comment: It adds the scaffold but there is no display of the login/logout & register buttons.
I have chosen the layout page, but nothing. I overcame half the problem, which i thank you for it. Hence that's the reason i didn't mark it (yet at least) as an answer.

Comment: You can describe your problem in detail and provide more information so that we can solve your problem.

Comment: Please check your `Views/Shared/_LoginPartial` then make sure it is referenced in the `_layout`.

Comment: You can choose to edit your question or ask a new question.

Comment: Am getting the same issue in VS2022 did u find an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to updated all `NuGet packages` from `Tools->Nuget Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Updates tab -> Update All.`

Comment: Hey may not want to upgrade certain dlls that can cause issues if on specific versions bad advice their its not a solution to the issue.